# Sublime Text 2: highlight '!important' in less files

Tags: less, sublimetext2, keyword, highlight

I have LESS package installed through Package Control (this one - https://github.com/danro/LESS-sublime/), but I can't figure out how to highlight '!important' in less files. I want to set color to red. How would that be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add something like this to your `.tmTheme` of your preferred color scheme.

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Don's keywords</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>keyword.operator.less</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF000</string> 
    </dict>
</dict>
```

For the OP, you could find the scope of `!important` by checking the `LESS.tmLanguage` file.  At around line 350:

```
<dict>
  <key>match</key>
  <string>/|!important|$|%|&amp;|\*|\-\-|\-|\+\+|\+|~|===|==|=|!=|!==|&lt;=|&gt;=|&lt;&lt;=|&gt;&gt;=|&gt;&gt;&gt;=|&lt;&gt;|&lt;|&gt;|!|&amp;&amp;|\|\||\?\:|(?&lt;!\()/=|%=|\+=|\-=|&amp;=|when\b|and\b|not\b</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>keyword.operator.less</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: FTR, @lawlist posted essentially the same answer 2 min before I did.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a section to your `.tmTheme` file relating to `keyword.operator.less` -- something similar to this?

```
<!-- BEGIN keyword.operator.less -->
<dict>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>keyword.operator.less</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#FF0000</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#FFFFFF</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
<!-- END keyword.operator.less -->
```